# How to set the split view control within a UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

few days to start the iPad development and i face the some problem,

In that the i create the one viewcontroller in which shows the numbers of the options like Deskboard then after open the splitview controller

Flow like following

```
View Controller
   |
   |->Splite view controller(with Tabbar controll)
                |
                |->Left controller(UITableview)
                |
                |->Right Controller(navigation controller)
```

Thus i expected output like below

[image]

so anyone can guide for solving the problem.

guys any ideas or work arounds?

Please let me know if I am not clear in my question.

Thanks and Regards,

Samuel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve this problem by Cocoa Matter solution thanks for it

And now form above solution i enhance the solution and now the problem solved.

following is the code for the solution
.h file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UISplitViewController *splitController;
```

.m file

```
   UIViewController *viewController5 = [[searchDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"searchDetail" bundle:nil];
    delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, navForLogin, navForContact, viewController5, nil]; 

    SearchVctr *viewController1 = [[SearchVctr alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchVctr" bundle:nil];
    FavouriteVctr *viewController2 = [[FavouriteVctr alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavouriteVctr" bundle:nil];
    self.splitController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    [self.splitController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil]];
    self.splitController.delegate = self;
    viewController5.view=self.splitController.view;

    delegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 4;
    delegate.imgV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"t4_ipad.png"]];
    delegate.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    delegate.self.imgV.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 48);
    [self presentModalViewController:delegate.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Thanks for the Reply,

Answer (score 0):

please see this which i make changes in app delegate.

steps1:
I took a tab bar navigation application template:

step 2:
Changes in App Delegate .m file take a UISplitView controller Object as property.

then make changes as i did below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.splitController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
[self.splitController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil]];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_splitController, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

it was working please take care of memory management

Answer (score 0):

Please check out below code

Add a new view controller for handling UISplitViewController called MasterVctr
Add two new controller for left view and rightview called LeftVCtr and RightVctr

In **MasterVCtr**

define

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

add following code into **viewDidLoad**

```
splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

table = [[LeftVCtr alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
detail = [[RightVctr alloc] initWithNibName:@"RightVctr" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *leftNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:table] autorelease];
UINavigationController *rightNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detail] autorelease];

splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftNav,rightNav, nil];
splitViewController.delegate = self;
self.view = splitViewController.view;
```